# Add item to ArrayList "recursively"

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, static, addition

I have an static ArrayList which I can only access from a class ("Sale"). In that ArrayList I want to add items of the same class. How can I add them from the constructor?

I've done it this way and it doesn't work:

```
public class Sale{
     private static ArrayList<Sale> sales;
     private Buyer buyer;
     private Item item;

     public Sale(Buyer buyer, Item item){
          this.buyer=buyer;
          this.item=item;
          sales.add(this);
     }
.....
```

Thanks in advance, I'm starting programming in Java.

Comment: Why would you want even to do that recursively. You do not need that. Since the variable is static, you can easily created a method and add the `Collection` there. I do not see any value in having this logic, when you can have a for loop and add the values there, through the static method, which references the static variable `sales`.

Comment: I would also ask: why do you want to do this? In the sense of: this smells like BAD design. Why should the Sale class ... maintain a list of Sales?! If your "shopping system" needs to keep lists of Sales objects; then heck; they should be in other places.

Comment: Agreeing with @Jägermeister, that is BAD practice.

Comment: I know this solution is quite awful, but I was asked to do so (it is an exercise). Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you understood the exercise?  An exercise is supposed to teach correct principles, and this is all wrong.  As an exercise it is recommending very bad practice.

Comment: Yes, I am _sure_. Thank you for your concern. I know it is not a good solution, but professors at university ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't *initialized* your `sales` ArrayList. You can do so by changing

```
private static ArrayList<Sale> sales;
```

to something like

```
private static ArrayList<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<Sale>();
```

**or** using the [diamond operator `<>`](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html) (Java 7+) like

```
private static ArrayList<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<>();
```

But I would suggest you [program to the `List` interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/2970947). Something like

```
private static List<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Another** possible option is a *static initializer*, like

```
private static List<Sale> sales;
static {
    sales = new ArrayList<>();
}
```